# How to block key strokes from closing the window and making it non resizable?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, fullscreen

I have a GUI application which requires a non resizable full screen at all times and also it needs to prevent closing of window using keystrokes.I used resizable(false,false) but that does nothing on macOS. Hence I thought *overrideredirect* would do the job.
However when I use it,the entry widgets can no longer be accessed which is essential for getting the inputs and the usual cmd+q closes the window as well.
 It seems to be a common problem and there seems to be no solution.This particular site http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/overrideredirect-vs-text-entry-etc-widget.698302/  had a little discussion but other than that I couldn't find much.
 I believe override redirect works on windows but causes problems for  other platforms. What other ways can be employed?

Answer (score 0):

I have a program that follows similar requirements, but in a restricted hardware access environment.
My solution was to simply remove the hardware keyboard and build an on-screen keyboard without the problem keys. It's a bit of a hack, but if you can control the hardware it's worth a look.